# How to echo array elements separated by hyphen in reverse order?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have this code:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

function recursive($array, $index) {      
    if($index == -1) return;
    echo $array[$index]."-";
    exit;
    recursive($array, $index-1);
}
recursive($array, 5);
```

**Current output:**

`6-5-4-3-2-1`

**Expected output:**

`1-2-3-4-5-6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get count of `array` and calculate its start position.
Here is the updated code

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$len = count($array);

function recursive($array, $index) {      
    global $len;

    if($index == -1) return;

    // Get count then subtract index to get start position
    echo $array[$len-1-$index]."-";

    recursive($array, $index-1);
}
recursive($array, 5);
?>
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/759488)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo implode('-', array_reverse($array));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

function recursive($array, $index)
{
    if ($index == -1)
        return;
    echo $array[count($array)-1-$index];
    if($index!=0)
        echo "-";
    recursive($array, $index - 1);
}

recursive($array, 5);
```

Comment: you may save the array length in a varible to avoid calculate each time.

Comment: @KrisRoofe You are right but i have changed the user's existing code. So that user can learn where he was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use String function strrev();

```
<?php
echo strrev("6-5-4-3-2-1"); // outputs "1-2-3-4-5-6"
?>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't use the correct input data.  Downvoted.